# C - Redirecting awk/sed stdout to pipe doesn't work

Tags: c, redirect, awk, pipe, stdout

So I have an exercise to do, and one part of this exercise requires us to execute a command passed as an argument, be able to pass it some strings on stdin, and get its output on stdout and stderr.
How I did it, I need to redirect the stdout and stderr (of the child, which is gonna call an exec) to a couple of pipes (other end of the pipes is held open by the parent).
I managed to do it, when I ask it to execute bash and send it "ls", it gives me what i want, where i want it. Same with cat and others.
Problem is, when I try executing awk or sed, nothing is ever written on the pipe. Ever.
If i leave stdout untouched, it does print it how it should. But as soon as i redirect the stdout, nothing.
I tried everything, select(), wait(), sleep() (even though it's not allowed). Nothing seems to work.

I made a minimum working example of what i mean (clearly, it lacks of conventions and mindful writing, as free() and close(), but it does it's job) which Is the one I'm attaching. The code works when i call it like this:
`./program $(which bash)`
It prompts for something, i write "ls" and it gives me the result expected
but when i try
`./program $(which awk) '{print $0;}'`
I get nothing at all

Here's the code (minimum working example):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int fdStdinP[2],fdStdoutP[2];
    char *string,*array[3];
    array[0]=argv[1];
    array[1]=argv[2];
    array[2]=0;
    pipe(fdStdinP);
    pipe(fdStdoutP);
    int pid=fork();
    if(pid==0){
        close(fdStdinP[1]);
        close(fdStdoutP[0]);
        dup2(fdStdinP[0],0);
        close(fdStdinP[0]);
        dup2(fdStdoutP[1],1);
        close(fdStdoutP[1]);
        //as suggested, the file descriptors are now closed
        execvp(argv[1],array);
        perror("");
        return 0;
    }
    close(fdStdinP[0]);
    close(fdStdoutP[1];
    string=calloc(1024,sizeof(char));
    read(0,string,1024);
    write(fdStdinP[1],string,1024);
    free(string);
    string=calloc(1024,sizeof(char));
    read(fdStdoutP[0],string,1024);
    printf("I have read:%s",string);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @cliff2310 Already did that. Is there a problem with what i wrote?

Comment: don't omit #include lines.  People should be able to paste your example to a file and compile it.

Comment: @stark sure, gonna add them back right now.

Comment: Boiler plate is `dup2(fd,0); close(fd);`. That is, close the fd that you just dup'd.

Comment: Your awk command is expecting input.  Where would it come from?

Comment: @stark it would come from string, which first is filled by read(0,string,1024), and then passed to write(fdStdinP[1],string,1024). Which i know works how it should since other commands work.

Comment: @WilliamPursell It's not working. Tried closing both and only one of the two. Why should it work?

Comment: @Tolatale There are many other issues.  The arguments you are passing to exec are also wrong.

Comment: If you leave the file desciptors open, the child will block on a read waiting for itself to close the open fd, which it never will do.  This is a common error that you are likely to hit (once you fix all the other issues) if you do not carefully close all fds

Comment: After `execvp()` fails, print an error message to standard error and do not exit with 0 because a status of 0 reports success.

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the parent or child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions.

Comment: @WilliamPursell how can it be wrong? It's a null terminated pointer of strings, as the man requires. Plus, it works (when i need to pass 2 or less argument, of course, not more) with other commands. Try calling it with bash and inputting "ls -l"

Comment: @JonathanLeffler perror after execvp ain't writing nothing. So i guess awk executes, but it doesn't send anything to the pipe. Also, already tried closing the file descriptors, but it's not working. Gonna update the code up here though.

Comment: But you have `execvp(argv[1], array); return 0;` which ain't using `perror()` and ain't reporting an error exit status.

Comment: Note that the sequence: `read(0,string,1024); write(fdStdinP[1],string,1024);` is wrong too. You should be capturing the return value from `read()` and using that in the `write()` — for example, `ssize_t nbytes = read(0, string, sizeof(string)); if (nbytes > 0) write(fdStdinP[1], string, nbytes);`, possibly with error checking on the `write()` too.  Remember that `read()` does not null terminate the data.

Comment: gdb says it is hanging in the last read waiting for 1024 characters from the child.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  I have the code at end and added it before return 0. should execvp fail, perror should clearly print. Yet it doesn't.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I already said in the post, that it is a Minimal working example and I'm not paying attention to error checking. This isn't the final product, this is merely to reproduce the problem. Since it works with bash and cat, I'm pretty sure that's not the problem. Since i know right now i'm writing less than 1024 bytes, and that i used calloc on string, string is surely null terminated.

Comment: Well, if you've redirected standard error to the parent, the parent has to read it and print it.  However, it looks like you're not really using the `fdStderrP` at all; get rid of that until you're ready to actually work with standard error. As it stands, the child should have 6 calls to `close()`, one for each end of 3 pipes.  They could all appear after the `dup2()` calls.  The `perror()` still doesn't show in the code you edited a couple of minutes ago, and you still exit successfully (`exit(0);`) if the `execvp()` fails.

Comment: @stark I guess it blocks there, but why? why isn't awk writing anything?

Comment: Because the input fd to awk is still open, I suspect.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler added it right now, thanks for reminding me. Also, as you noticed, I'm not using fdStderrP, and i just opened it, so it defintely has no repurcussion on the rest of the code and perror is definitely not writing anyhting.

Comment: @stark could be, but how? I just closed both fds in use.

Comment: After you send input to `fdStdinP[1]` you can close it to tell awk it's input has ended.

Comment: Works now.  Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk continues to wait for input and buffers its output, so appears to hang.  Closing the sending end will tell awk that it's input has ended so that it will end and flush its output.

```
write(fdStdinP[1],string,1024);
close(fdStdinP[1]);    // just added this line.
```

Comment: I can't believe it was this little thing. I even tried to send an EOF and a 0 to comunicate it. Thank you so much.